# Python ctypes how to deal with malloc/free?

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I'm trying to convert a .cpp file to .py using the ctypes library.

Some basic operations are working, but I'm struggling when using typedef structs as well as malloc/free.

Here what I got:

module.h:

```
typedef struct
{   
    CHAR8 name[M_MODNAMELEN_A];       /**< Name of the module. */
} MODULE_NAME;
typedef struct
{
    UINT16 countModules;       /**< Count of module names.*/
    MODULE_NAME * names;       /**< Array of module names.     */
} MODULE_LIST;
```

program.cpp:

```
UINT16 countModules;
SINT32 ret = GetCountModules(targetHandle, &countModules);
if(ret!=M1C_OK)
    return ret;
MODULE_LIST modList;
modList.names = (MODULE_NAME*)malloc(countModules * sizeof(MODULE_NAME));
// do some calculations
free( modList.names );
```

program.py:

```
from ctypes import *
c_lib = CDLL('libXXYY.so')
class MODULE_NAME(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('name', c_byte)
    ]
    def __repr__(self):
        return '({0})'.format(self.name)

class MODULE_LIST(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('countModules', c_uint),
        ('names', POINTER(MODULE_NAME))     ### Is this conversion correct?
    ]
    def __repr__(self):
        return '({0}, {1})'.format(self.x, self.y)

count_modules = c_uint()
ret = c_long(c_lib.GetCountModules(target_handle, byref(count_modules)))
if ret.value != M1C_OK:
    return ret
# Up to here everything works fine..
# Allocating memory for the list of module names
modList = MODULE_LIST()
modList.names =  ### How to convert the malloc line?
## Some calcs
### How to convert the free( modList.names ); line?
```

The python runs ok up to the "modList.names = " line.. There I've tried several things (for example: modList.names = (MODULE_NAME)count_modules.value * sizeof(MODULE_NAME()) ) but all my tries have failed.

How should I translate the malloc line from cpp to python?

How should I translate the free line from cpp to python?

Are the translations of the typedef struct to class correct? Specially the one of "MODULE_LIST".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How should I translate the malloc line from cpp to python?

Usually, a DLL that returns something like MODULE_LIST does the malloc for you,
and provides a function to free it later, but if you have to fill one out yourself
an array type is created by multiplying a type by a size, then calling it to create an instance:

```
m = MODULE_LIST()
m.countModules = countModules
m.names = (MODULE_NAME * countModules)() # create instance of array
```

> How should I translate the free line from cpp to python?

If allocated as above, Python will free it when there are no more references to the memory, such as when `m` above goes out of scope.  You can call `del m` to explicitly dereference the memory.  If `m` is the only reference, it will be freed.

> Are the translations of the typedef struct to class correct? Specially the one of "MODULE_LIST".

No, `CHAR8 name[M_MODNAMELEN_A];` is an array, so multiply a type by a length to make the correct array type:

```py
M_MODNAMELEN_A = 100  # some constant that wasn't defined by OP

class MODULE_NAME(Structure):
    _fields_ = ('name',c_char * M_MODNAMELEN_A),
```

`MODULE_LIST` has a 16-bit integer, so use the correct 16-bit type:

```py
class MODULE_LIST(Structure):
    _fields_ = (('countModules',c_uint16),
                ('names',POINTER(MODULE_NAME)))
```

To call the function correctly, best practice is to define `.argtypes` and `.restype` for the function to improve error checking:

```py
# Assume "int GetCountModules(HANDLE handle, UINT16* pCount)" exists in dll.
dll = CDLL('./somedll')
dll.GetCountModules.argtypes = c_void_p, POINTER(c_uint16)
dll.GetCountModules.restype = c_int

# Make an instance to the output parameter and pass it by reference:
countModules = c_uint16()
ret = dll.GetCountModules(targetHandle, byref(countModules))
```